# What is the 'right' data structure to turn app features on/off based on 'type' of account?

Tags: ruby

My app has 10 features that are enabled/disabled depending upon which of the 3 'types' of account a user has.

Currently, I have 10 methods (one per feature) along the lines of:

```
def is_FEATURENAME_enabled
  case currentuser.accounttype
  when "A", "C"  # account types allow to see that feature
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Then, in each place where I potentially disable a feature, I do

```
if foo.is_SOMEFEATURE_enable
   do stuff to enable that feature
end
```

It works. It's not that hard to maintain. But there should be a better way. I suspect the right solution is to define some sort of structure (hash? I dunno) in one place that maps enabled features to accounttypes, then have a single method that I call something like:

```
if foo.is_feature_enabled(:FEATURENAME)
  do stuff to enable feature
end
```

where the method `is_feature_enabled` looks at `currentuser.accountype` and checks the mapping structure to see if the identified feature is enabled.

And I suspect the DRY way to define that mapping (given I have WAY more features than account types) is to list all the features ONCE then for each feature list the accounttypes that have access to that feature (not the other way around). That way when I add a new feature I only have to edit ONE line in the mapping. Something like:

```
FeatureA: usertype1
FeatureB: usertype1, usertype3
FeatureC: usertype2
...
```

seems more logical and easier to maintain than:

```
usertype1: FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureD, FeatureG
usertype2: FeatureC, FeatureD
usertype3: FeatureB, FeatureD, FeatureG, FeatureH
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, and instructive for learning The Right Way to do stuff in ruby.

Comment: I don't suppose you're using RoR? In that case, have a look at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan if you haven't already. It can give you ideas to implement your own DSL for managing authorization. If you are using RoR, well, you can simply use the gem.

Comment: I would suggest using a trust-based model instead of a role-based model, where each user has a single trust-score.  Then you just mark each feature with its required minimum trust-score.  This is comparable to how SO works with user reputation scores (and SO has quite a bit more than 10 unlockable features), and much simpler and more scalable than a role-based model.

Comment: @aroth I agree with what you say about a trust-based model-- it can be  easier for many, perhaps most cases. However, a role-based model is indispensable in some cases, where there isn't a strict "ladder." (E.g., there are things teachers can do that students can't, like grade papers, while there are things students can do that teachers can't, like submit papers. Or, cops can file arrest paperwork, but not sentence people, and judges can sentence people but not arrest people.) So think about your particular requirements and try to get away with a trust-model if you can, but not if you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion. Yes I'm using rails 3 on Heroku. And devise. However, cancan is beyond my meager abilities to implement... and I'd need such a tiny subset of it that I thought rolling my own would be the way to go for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've pretty much discovered the best way to do it on your own-- what you suggest is wise. Just use the feature name as a lookup key for your hash, then take the resulting list and check whether that list contains the account type of the current user.

E.g.,

```
# For example...
$AllowedUserCastes = {
 :CanLogin => ["admin", "paiduser", "crazyuser", "anonymous"],
 :CanDrink => ["admin", "21yearolduser", "crazyuser"],
 :CanArrest => ["admin", "police"]
}

def featureAllowed?( whichFeature )
    $AllowedUserCastes[whichFeature].include? currentUserCaste()
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Enough of a newbie that actually I wasn't sure how to actually DO that... so your kind example is deeply appreciated!

Comment: No problem! Keep at it and you'll go far!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for some kind of [event dispatcher](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/trunk/book/01-Event-Dispatcher). I've yet to bump into a [very good one](http://dev.lithify.me/drafts/source/en/02_lithium_basics/02_filters.wiki) in ruby. But I'm sure I've missed a few, so I'll be happy to be stood corrected in the comments.